# Im trying to get select query response in angularjs file

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to send Select query response to angularjs file.

```
Php file

header('Content-Type: application/json');    
echo json_encode(pg_fetch_row($res));



angularjs file

$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'getData.php'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.products= response.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

reponse is this `Object {data: "↵ ", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}`

how can i get 'data'.  what is this symbol "↵ " ?

Comment: Any php sided error messages? Sure you are not outputting anything before header, not even a whitespace or line break?